# Fill a set array (24 x 20) which changes based on different cells

Tags: arrays, excel, grouping

I'm sure I'm overthinking this, but I believe Excel can handle it.  I'm trying to take various numbers (up to 9 different numbers and begin at cell 1,1 and fill across 24 columns on row 1 (1,24) and then down 1 row (2,24) and then fill backwards and subsequently in an "S" shape through out the first 240 cells.
I may have the number 9 (A1) as my first variable, so 1,1 through 1,9 would be 5XL (but remember I have 24 columns) so, my next variable would then take over from (B1) as 6, so the next six cells would be 4XL.  Now I'm up to 1,15.  I also need to be able to change the results array.  I hope you get the picture.
[Screen Shot of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIfc5.png)

Comment: Are you looking for formula or VBA?

Comment: Though based on what you've described, it would probably be easiest to implement this using VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar example for Winstek1]

Then this macro will produce those results shown in E2:AB20

```
Sub PopulateTable()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vSourceData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As String
    Dim bBackwards As Boolean, bFull As Boolean
    Dim lRowIndex As Long, lColIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        vSourceData = .Value
    End With
    ReDim aResults(1 To 20, 1 To 24)

    lRowIndex = 1
    lColIndex = 1
    bBackwards = False
    bFull = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(vSourceData, 1)
        For j = 1 To vSourceData(i, 1)
            aResults(lRowIndex, lColIndex) = vSourceData(i, 2)
            If bBackwards Then lColIndex = lColIndex - 1 Else lColIndex = lColIndex + 1
            If lColIndex = 0 Then
                lRowIndex = lRowIndex + 1
                lColIndex = 1
                bBackwards = Not bBackwards
            ElseIf lColIndex = UBound(aResults, 2) + 1 Then
                lRowIndex = lRowIndex + 1
                lColIndex = UBound(aResults, 2)
                bBackwards = Not bBackwards
            End If
            If lRowIndex > UBound(aResults, 1) Then bFull = True    'No more room in results array
            If bFull Then Exit For
        Next j
        If bFull Then Exit For
    Next i

    With ws.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2))
        .ClearContents      'Clear previous results (if any)
        .Value = aResults   'Output results
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Next level? What if I want to segment the same array and add a different result in the last 4 columns or the middle 4 rows. So, I have 480 cells with 3 products in different sizes but still can only use the same 480 slots.  I may need 80 (Last 4 columns), 60 (Last 3 columns), etc. OR maybe need 96 which would be the middle 4 rows, etc.  Thanks for your help @tigeravatar !

Comment: @Winstek1 This is a new question with new requirements.  Please create a new question that details the new requirements with sample before and after data.  Additionally, you can link to this post in your new question for reference

Comment: I'm thinking this is just a bunch of IF scenarios based on certain cells.  EX: IF A1=80 then "the last 4 columns use Array XXXX as the source"